# Howto set part of Azure AD Blazor Server App open for public

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, azure-webapps, microsoft-identity-platform

**My goal**

I've built a Blazor Server web application.
A **part** of this application requires authentication (limited to users in our organisation). The other part should be completely open to everyone on the internet.

**What I did**

I've setup and configured the 'Microsoft identity platform', so the app is registered in Azure AD under 'app-registrations' and 'enterprise applications'.

All of the Azure settings seems to work now, for example if i change settings like 'Assignment required?' i see the differences in behavior.

**My problem**

The application as a whole requires authentication right now, where I need parts to be public. Adding `[AllowAnonymous]` to some of my Razor components my seems to be ignored. Is it possible to open up parts of this application to the public?

**Update**

For testing purpose i've added two route handlers to my Program.cs like this:

```
app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
}).AllowAnonymous();

app.MapGet("/admin", () =>
{
}).RequireAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Now when I navigate to my application url, it doesn't route me to the microsoft login page. When i add /admin to the url is does. So i guess i have to change the routing to 'open up' a part of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to split my application into two seperate projects. One for the public part, one for the admin login.